# Unity - How do I click on a specific object instead of just the whole screen in a different object?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm coding a top down game, with point and click movement. Currently you are able to click on the map, but you can also click outside the map to move there. I added colliders to the walls, but you still try and go outside. Code example:

```
if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1)) {'move'}
```

But what I want is something like this:

```
if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1) on MAP) //map is the object
```

So I want to be able to only click on the map, and if you click outside the map, it won't do anything. Thanks!
My script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 10f;
    Vector2 lastClickedPos;
    //Rect inRect = new Rect(82.80f, -83.20f, 164.90f, 163.29f);
    bool moving;

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1) && GameObject.CompareTag("clickedOn")){ // && inRect.Contains(Input.mousePosition)

            lastClickedPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
            moving = true;
        }

        if (moving && (Vector2)transform.position != lastClickedPos)
        {
            float step = speed * Time.deltaTime;
            transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, lastClickedPos, step);
        }
        else
        {
            moving = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: have you looked at tutorials?

Comment: i have, but i couldn't find any that explained this. If you could link me to one, that would be great :)

Comment: Here look at this one https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_yf5vzZ2sYE

Comment: hmm... this isn't the type of thing I'm looking for, but thanks anyway (btw im sorry if its confusing but its actually a 2d game it just automatically set it to 3d) :) I'm more looking for something that registers when I click on something because i need to be able to make the clicking work for click to move, but also only be able to click on the map

Comment: Well. You either try ipointerdownhandler or raycast. If you found neither I’d be surprised

Answer (score 0):

I think you can resolve your issue using tags or layers. I'll just list how to setup tags since it has a lot less setup vs. doing layers.

First off you'll need to create a tag and since Unity has good documentation on stuff like this I'll just link it here: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Tags.html

Once you created your tag and tagged the ground/environment/area you want to have be clickable with the tag then you just need to find the object you want to collided with and use CompareTag so to put that in an example here is what your if statement could look like:

```
if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1) && collidedObject.CompareTag("TagNameGoesHere"))
{
   //Movement goes here
}
```

Just to note I've named the gameObject that was found to collidedObject but you can name it whatever you want.

Hopefully this helps, let me know if I need to clarify something, it has been awhile since I've done a stackoverflow answer so I may have left something out.

Edit: Alright so adding onto this, you'll need to also look into how to do raycasting to check what object you click on so you can determine if it's a spot you can move to.

I've just tested this in a project just to make sure I understand it (I've used raycast a lot but never really done point to click movement before).

Essentially I've broken down things into 3 statements, which you can add together into one if statement but it's more so I can explain everything in detail:

```
if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1))
```

What you use currently, we want to make sure we only do the next few checks when we click

```
if (Physics.Raycast(playerCamera.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition), out hit, Mathf.Infinity))
```

So this here, is essentially drawing a line from a position, in this bit we are using the player camera which is just a regular camera reference and converting a point on screen into a ray which we then set the length to be Mathf.Infinity (this can be whatever float, I've just used this for an example) and then we output the hit object to hit which is a RaycastHit struct.

```
if (hit.collider != null && hit.collider.CompareTag("TagNameGoesHere"))
```

Now we finally check to see if the collider is not null (in case we hit the sky or something, which shouldn't happen for you in a top down game) and also that the object has right tag. Again you need to setup the tags which I've listed above and make sure you set the correct game objects in scene to have the correct tag. After which you should be able to move to the position (using the position you've setup and such is fine)

So it should look something like this:

```
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1))
        {
        if (Physics.Raycast(playerCamera.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition), out rayCastHit, Mathf.Infinity))
        {
            if (hit.collider != null && hit.collider.CompareTag("TagNameGoesHere"))
            {
                //Movement goes here
            }
        }
    }
```

Make sure to also put a reference to the camera and RayCastHit objects (these are the playerCamera and rayCastHit variables in the above). For my example script that I created I made them global variables.

Comment: So, collidedObject could be called anything, like GameMap, or is that to check that it has been collided with?
Edit: I tried collidedObject and MobaMap(my object name) and neither worked. It came up with this error: The name 'collidedObject' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Also, if I try GameObject.CompareTag('clickedOn'), it comes up with this error: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'GameObject.CompareTag(string)'

Comment: Okay so maybe a little more context is needed, would you be able to update your question with what your script looks like? I was sorta under the impression that when you click via the if statement with Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1) in it, that you'd have some reference to the game object that it collided with.

Comment: You need to use " inside the compare tag bit so CompareTag('clickedOn') would be wrong but CompareTag("clickedOn") would work. make sure the tag is made though otherwise it won't work.

Comment: k i added the script :)

Comment: Hey, haven't head back from you, was my answer able to help you out? @TowerOfGray11